# Google Sheets Script disappearing variables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am reading a large data matrix from a worksheet into google sheets script. In some cases, the cell being read from the sheet has never been touched. In those cases, when I set a variable (example: `datacellcontents`) equal to that cell’s content (`getRange(“”).getValue();`) in the debugger, the variable `datacellcontents` disappears from the list in the debugger and when the variable `datacellcontents` is used in a formula, the script aborts.

`Datacellcontents != undefined` and `Datacellcontents != null`. It just seems to disappear. This could happen in a for loop after several interations with all the data filled in  worked perfectly. Anyone know a fix to track when this occurs? Example of code below:

Note: c,g are not in debugger since no data on sheet in those locations.

[image: picture of debugger]

Comment: There is an open issue with the debugger in V8. Try disabling the V8 engine fo to Run -> disable V8 in the script editor.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for the `datacellcontents` variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the length of the disappearing variable, it is set to 0, which you can use as a trapping result.

example:

```
if (AAA.length == 0) {
    browser.msgbox ("Invalid AAA");
}
```